# Please help reduce the following circuit to an equivalent circuit with single resistor and source

Tags: electrical, network

[image: Circuit Diagram]

Please help reduce the following circuit to an equivalent form as I am unable to understand the given solution in the book. If required I will share the solution later.
Thanks in advance.

---

@jonk, @jsotola, @MarkU thanks for the prompt reply and apologies for the inconvenience. Please find below solution, what I need your help is in understanding why the voltage source branch has been removed. As per my understanding since the voltage in the branch becomes zero, there should be a short circuit and we should take the 20 ohm resistor branches in consideration.Please do let me know if any more details are required.

[image: SOLUTION]

Comment: It's inconsiderate of the time of others and perhaps lazy of you, if you already know how to do some steps but cannot be bothered to show what you know. It is disingenuous, if you don't know anything at all about solving it, but imply that you do by saying you will share that information at a later time. It would be much better all around if you'd please put some effort into your own questions and/or admit details about what you don't know. I've been known to often just blast out answers because I can use blank questions like this as a simple foil in order to teach others. But sometimes no.

Comment: `help` means "to assist with work" ... you have not shown any work, therefore it is impossible to help you  .... you are asking for someone to do the work for you

Comment: This is not a practical working circuit: **its only purpose is to help reinforce a lesson. What technique were you most recently taught for solving this kind of problem?** When I parse this schematic, I see that some of the sources cancel out, and some are redundant, so about half of the circuit elements drawn are irrelevant "red herring" tricks. No practical circuit would be designed this way. What's left looks to me like a *Thevenin or Norton source* with two resistors in parallel combination. **If you don't share your thought process, nobody can see where you're getting stuck.**

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! This appears to be a homework question. As such, you need to show us your work so far, and explain which part of the question you're having trouble with. For future reference: Homework questions on EE.SE enjoy/suffer a special treatment. We don't provide complete answers, we only provide hints or Socratic questions, and only when you have demonstrated sufficient effort of your own. Otherwise, we would be doing you a disservice, and getting swamped by homework questions at the same time. See also [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5120/7036).

Comment: **"reduce the following circuit to an equivalent form"** Was the original question *really* posed this way? There are multiple answers, depending on which two of the 5 nodes you pick. And even at that, I'm assuming you reduce 5 nodes to 2.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the update. That helps a lot. And yes, the step you are asking about is a correct transformation. One way of seeing it is that the \$0\:\text{V}\$ source means there cannot be a voltage ***difference*** across that \$20\:\Omega\mid\mid 20\:\Omega\$ pair. So there cannot be any current through it and since no current through it is possible, you can simply remove the \$20\:\Omega\mid\mid 20\:\Omega\$ pair from the circuit without affecting the results.

This fact leaves the \$0\:\text{V}\$ source. But it's not necessary as placing a wire there achieves the same thing.

That's pretty much all there is to that step you are asking about.